# module initialization error: ReferenceError when using kms.decrypt

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a function which decrypt the encrypted variable which is sent to it. I just copied and paste the code from the button called code which is beside encypt button in aws lambda console. Here is my code after some modification:

```
var decryptEnvVariable = function (encryptedEnvVar) {
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const kms = new AWS.KMS();

    kms.decrypt({CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(encryptedEnvVar, 'base64')}, (err, data) = > {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error in decryption of environment variable', err);
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve(data.Plaintext.toString('ascii'));
});
});
return promise;

}
```

So when I call the above I get the following error:

```
``START RequestId: eb7dd1ac-4549-11e7-b41b-071b15adaf2f Version: $LATEST
  module initialization error: ReferenceError
 kms.decrypt({CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(encryptedEnvVar, 'base64')}, (err, 
 data) = > {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
 ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
 at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
 at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
 at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
 at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
 at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
 at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
 END RequestId: eb7dd1ac-4549-11e7-b41b-071b15adaf2f
 REPORT RequestId: eb7dd1ac-4549-11e7-b41b-071b15adaf2f Duration: 56.15 ms  
 Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 18 MB
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you sure is not just the `= >` to `=>` (without the space)?

Comment: Ooooops this was the last thing I could think of. Thanks a lot :)